# Визуализация задачи протекания (перколяция) в Java

Tags: java, визуализация

Есть двумерный массив 100х100 с integer значениями: нули, единицы, двойки. Необходимо получить изображение перколяционного кластера (на подобии рисунка ниже). Другими словами, для белого изображения размером 100х100 пикселей, закрасить пиксели черным цветом в тех координатах, в которых присутствуют двойки. Ищется незамудренное решение с примерами, чтобы понять, как это работает)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Задача решена. Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чем проблема пробежаться по массиву и отрисовать его?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется вопрос заключается в том как работать с изображениями в Java.

Имеется официальный достаточно хороший [туториал](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) (на английском), основные моменты:

- Класс изображения — [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).
- Он представляет собой двумерный массив пикселей
- Каждый пиксель кодируется числом типа `int`, с помощью одной из [цветовых моделей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C), обычно используется [`RGB`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB) (в коде записывается как `0xRRGGBB`, где вместо `RR`, `GG` и `BB` нужно подставить значение соответствующей цветовой компоненты, от 0 до 255, но в [hex записи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))
- [`new BufferedImage(ширина, высота, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#BufferedImage-int-int-int-) — создание изображения фиксированного размера с цветовой моделью [`RGB`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_INT_RGB)

Изменение и получение цвета пикселя:

- [`.setRGB(x, y, rgb)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB-int-int-int-) — задание цвета пикселя с координатами `(x, y)`
- [`.getRGB(x, y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB-int-int-) — получение цвета пикселя с координатами `(x, y)`

После задания цветов всех пикселей изображение можно использовать различными способами, например [сохранить в файл](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) вот так:

[`ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File("имяфайла.png"));`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write-java.awt.image.RenderedImage-java.lang.String-java.io.File-)

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень помогли!

Comment: Если увеличить плотность точек, то происходит переполнение стека вызовов. Пробовал решить эту проблему с помощью `dispose`, но не получилось. Я так понимаю, нужно обнулить данные для переменной BufferedImage?

Comment: @Artorias точки рекурсией заполняются?

Comment: Да, я использую рекурсивную заливку для значений массива.

Comment: @Artorias возможно из-за ошибки рекурсия получается бесконечная, либо её глубина действительно очень большая, можно увеличить размер стека (запускать программу вот так: `java -Xss64m`, где вместо `64m` подставить размер стека), либо написать нерекурсивный алгоритм

Comment: Увеличил размер стека, все работает без ошибок. Спасибо!